# Basic Notation Help Needed : Classical Mechanics, Unit Vectors

Tags: classical-mechanics, vectors, notation

Can someone help me with some basic notation?  Here's a situation where I'm surely missing some trivial piece of the puzzle:

Example 1:  given $W = \frac{1}{2}cpAv^2$ (air resistance), adding a unit vector in the opposite direction of the particles velocity grants $\frac{1}{2}cpAv^2 \frac{-\mathbf{v}}{v}$.

This then turns into $-\frac{1}{2}cpAv\mathbf{v}$.  Ignore $\frac{1}{2}cpA$ term.
Question: what is the difference between these two vectors $v$ and $\mathbf{v}$ for velocity?  One of them should be my initial velocity of the object (I'm assuming $v$), but what about $\mathbf{v}$ - is it just the directional information alone?  Or is there something more clever I'm missing here?

I found a similar situation when dealing with the Dirac delta function, but hopefully this can easily be cleared up in this simpler situation.

Comment: I'm interested in the "similar situation when dealing with the Dirac delta function", since I really can't see the connection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small error  here: you say, "...these two *vectors* $v$ and $\mathbf{v}$" (emphasis mine). The problem there is that $v$ is not a vector. Rather, it's the *magnitude* of a vector; specifically, it is the magnitude of the velocity vector $\mathbf{v}$. This is actually implicit in your derivation: you created a unit vector in the direction of the motion of the object by dividing the vector $\mathbf{v}$ by its length $v$.

So, of course, $\mathbf{v}$ encodes both the speed and the direction of motion, and this is the instantaneous velocity at the current time, just as $v$ is the speed at the current time. This is important, because your expression for the drag force is meant to be the force exerted by the fluid through which the object is traveling at the current time. (So, neither of them are the initial velocity. The initial velocity doesn't show up in this expression because the *current* drag force only depends on the current velocity, not on the initial velocity.)

Comment: Wonderful answer, thank you.  It helped me draw the connection between the mathematical symbols world and the physical one.